# Posting a list with a missing number within the list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I have a form whereby I post a list of information.

So the list can be like so.

```
Person[0].FullName
Person[0].Address

Person[1].FullName
Person[1].Address

Person[2].FullName
Person[2].Address

Person[3].FullName
Person[3].Address
```

When I POST this information and run my update comment, it all works fine. The List<> model comes back with 4 records.

However, when I remove one of the middle records using jQuery, it removes the whole line from the HTML. So I end up with, for example, the scenario below.

```
Person[0].FullName
Person[0].Address

Person[2].FullName
Person[2].Address

Person[3].FullName
Person[3].Address
```

But now when I POST the information, the List<> count is now 1, because it's ignoring everything after the removal. I'm guessing it's because the List is now not sequential?

Has anyone come across the same issue before and know a way to save all items?

Thanks

EDIT - HTML

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.PersonsViewModel.Count(); i++)
{
    <div id="clone_@i" class="form-group clone">
        <div class="col-sm-6 has-feedback">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonsViewModel[i].FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PersonsViewModel[i].FullName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 has-feedback">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonsViewModel[i].Address, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PersonsViewModel[i].Address)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are breaking List chain and it lost index of list .Maybe you can try controller-side edit.I met this issue in the past and fix it in controller.

Comment: When the form is POSTed to the Controller, it's already lost the items within the Model.